# Mix Library Groups with one-line variables in Azure DevOps build yaml

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is it possible to mix variable groups and yaml one-line variables?

I know this is possible

```yaml
variables:
- group: my-group
- name: Variable1
    value: Value1
```

But how can I achieve this:

```yaml
variables:
- group: my-group
  Variable1: Value1
```

Declaring one-line variables is much more comfortable and easy to read, and works when there's no library group reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You can't use list and mapping variables in the same variables section

#### More details

From [YAML schema - variables definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/variables?view=azure-pipelines):

The variables keyword uses two syntax forms: variable list and mapping (string dictionary).

In mapping syntax, all keys are variable names and their values are variable values.

```yaml
variables:
  MY_VAR: 'my value'
  ANOTHER_VAR: 'another value'
```

To use variable templates, you must use list syntax. List syntax requires you to specify whether you're mentioning a variable (`name`), a variable group (`group`), or a template (`template`).

```yaml
variables:
  - group: my-variable-group-name
  - name: myReadOnlyVar
    value: myValue
    readonly: true
```

You can't use list and mapping variables in the same variables section, but you can combine `name`, `group`, and `template` when using list syntax.